# Fetching the value from database to the selection box

Tags: hibernate, struts2

There are three different selection boxes on signup page.
When I select "India" from the first selection box then all the state from "India" should be fetched from table in the second selection box and if select any state then regarding city of that particular state should be fetched from table in the third selection box.

We are using Struts2 with Hibernate

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
    if(externalUser.getPerson().getAddress().getCity().getState()
                   .getCountry().getId() + "" != null) {
        degreeList = degreeDao.findAll();
        setCountryList((List<Country>) countryDao.findAll());
        setStateList((List<State>)stateDao.findAll("country_ID", externalUser.getPerson().getAddress().getCity().getState().getCountry().getId()));
        setCityList((List<City>)stateDao.findAll("state_ID",externalUser.getPerson().getAddress().getCity().getState().getId()));
    } else {
        degreeList = degreeDao.findAll();
        setCountryList((List<Country>) countryDao.findAll());
    }

    return SUCCESS;
  }
```

Comment: Man, you really like chaining methods. Demeter will be angry with you.

Comment: (1) Something plus `""` will never be null. (2) Your DAO is *really* confusing; first, it should be type-safe, second, findAll() is very uncommunicative and counter-intuitive. (3) Both `degreeList` and `countryList` can be removed from the conditional. See non-answer for cleaned-up example, although Demeter still a bit peeved.

Answer (score 1):

*Not an answer; code cleanup.*

Consider writing this method something more like the following snippet.

[Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) will still be a bit [miffed](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter), but the rest of the code is easier to think about.

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
    setDegreeList(degreeDao.findAll());
    setCountryList(countryDao.findAll());

    State state = externalUser.getPerson().getAddress().getCity().getState();
    if (state.getCountry().getId() != null) {
        setStateList(stateDao.findStatesForCountry(state.getCountry().getId()));
        setCityList(stateDao.findCitiesForState(state.getId()));
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Like the Duke Nukem would say: "aaah, much better" ;-) and much more clearer ofc.

Answer (score 0):

Go for using some Ajax calling.When first value seleted form the drop down send that value to the Action and fetch the states based on the country.
send results as `JSON` data parse it at your jsp side fill the combo box.repeat the same cycle for district.

One easy way to use Struts2-Jquery plugin which has this type of select boxes.here is one for your reference

[Struts2-Jquery Plugin Select tag](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SelectTag)

I will prefer to use plain Jquery and send results as `JSON` data from my action class using `JSON` plugin for struts2 and parse data myself using Jquery that will give me more flexibility and control.

It never advisable to use such deep chaining of methods not only it will hinder the readability of your program but also make it hard to maintain at later stages.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you are trying to do, it uses the above mentioned Struts2 Jquery Plugin.

http://www.onlinexamples.com/showfullexample.action?idexamples=48&title=Dependent%20Select%20-%20Dependent%20Dropdowns%20-%20Triple%20Select%20Using%20Jquery

Comment: It might just be me, but code samples should be free of comments left-over from someone who didn't configure their IDE in a meaningful way :)